# activating a custom new window while debuging in visual studio

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, debugging

in code below I show information on my application , if there is something that was not set
(...in one of the classes or methods) correctly a window pops up with the current message telling what was missing .

there is only one problem I wonder if and how could this be done, the application is frozen while still debugging so I can not move the window or click on it's control,

**is there any workaround you think of** I could apply ?

```
void SomeMainThreadMethod()
{
    new System.Threading.Thread(() => ProcessSomeLongRunningTask()).Start();
}
//then from another helper class
void ProcessSomeLongRunningTask()
{
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>CustomW.MsgBoxShow(" Title ", "Msg")), System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, could you explain your question some more?

Comment: @BradleyUffner think of new window that pops up , you can not move it while debugger is running(F5) steps then window pops , can not activate it...

Comment: You can't interact with windows while stepping through, the debugger effectively freezes your program.  Maybe we can help you find another way around your problem if you explain why you think you need to be able to interact with the window while stepping though code?

Comment: @BradleyUffner ok. fair enough. it is a start of my own debugger, it works fine when my program is now over 40K lines of code across 10 or so files , so it is effective if I am using a class in a wrong way, so in every class on every method I report if parameter passed was not expected or the order of the calls was not a designed . as it works fine for me I was thinking how could I do it outside of the control of the visual studio. another process ?

Comment: @BradleyUffner how  about `System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream`

Comment: If you use another process to display your error messages it should avoid the problem of the UI locking up. `NamedPipeClientStream` would definitely allow you to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that you're processing your message box on your main dispatcher thread and as you know this defaults as a dialog box and steals focus from the main application window.

So you could try executing the message box in the new thread you create or you could create your own custom user control with the same features as the message box but it won't inherit that tools behavior.

You can still run it from a secondary thread like you created, but remember to wrap anything that interacts with objects made by the main dispatcher as a delegate action

```
       public void LongProcess()
       {
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
            delegate
               {

                //Complex code goes here

               this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
               {

                  //Any requests for controls or variables that you need
                  //from the main application running on the main dispatcher
                  //goes here

               }));


                //Finally once you've got the information to return to
                //your user call a message box here and populate the 
                //message accordingly.

                MessageBox.Show("", "");

                //If a message box fails or isn't good enough
                //create your own user control and call it here like:

                usrConMessage msg = new usrConMessage();
                msg.strTitle = "Whatever";
                msg.strContent = "Whatever";
                msg.show(); //Not a dialog so doesn't steal focus

                //That is normally how I would go about providing a
                //unique and polished user experience.

               }
             ));
            t.Start();
      }
```